# Printing contents of an array in a non-sequential order using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

Having trouble printing the contents of my array in a non synchronized way. I am looking to iterate through and output the letters "A" , "B" , "C" in a non sequential manner from a static array of strings using Threads to print the loop.

Here is my code:

```
public class ThreadWithExtends extends Thread {

    public ThreadWithExtends() {
        super();
    }

    public void run() {
        String[] arr = { "A", "B", "C" };
        int num = 10;
        try {
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
                    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
                }
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

My `TestThread` class:

```
public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ThreadWithExtends().start();
    }

}
```

My Output : `A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C`

My Desired Output : `C A B A B C B A C ..` etc , not sequential like above.

Comment: You have one thread doing sequential work...

Comment: Why? Why do people want things not deterministic with threads? They are not deterministic for every day use. They are deterministic somewhere deep down. Why care?

Comment: Although have created a thread but it's still a single thread. Inside the run it's nothing but sequential flow of execution. What you need is have your for loop on the main thread and create multiple threads for iterating and printing the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you aren't executing any code in parallel. You only created **one thread** that prints some statements sequentially. You need to create **three threads** that print stuff on their own, like so:

```
public class Printer extends Thread {
    private String mText;

    public Printer(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int num = 1_000;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print(mText + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Printer("A").start();
    new Printer("B").start();
    new Printer("C").start();
}
```

Now you have three threads that run in parallel. Prints should be mixed now.

---

Note that in general you shouldn't care about how the scheduler schedules the threads. It tries to optimize and it works well. It probably has its reasons why it scheduled this or that way. You can assign priorities to threads if you want to tell the scheduler your preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, appreciate it.

Comment: Chances are the output will _not_ be mixed @averageCoder.  Just because you have multiple threads don't mean that you will get interleaved output and certainly it won't be perfectly interleaved.